# Compare two csv file using in C#

Tags: c#

I need to find out difference between two csv files programatically.
Is there any way to find out the difference without using any loops?

Please help me.

Comment: What format do you need the differences to be in?

Comment: If you need differnce in data, than yes you need. If you just need to know if files are different than no

Comment: Read both csv file into list and then apply Linq set operation

Comment: without a loop?!? everything runs with loops...
reading files such as csv will be done by using reader objects. You read the data by looping through it's lines... so reading the textfile alone will require a loop...

Comment: You could read the file and place each line in a collection. However, that would not take into account additions and deletions, it would simply expose the differences. Of course its possible to figure out the differences between files otherwise a program like Winmerge wouldn't exist.  It would be not possible to read the entire file, place each line into a collection, without a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the following links ?
If not, then you should.

- [C# - Comparing two CSV Files and giving an output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458355/c-comparing-two-csv-files-and-giving-an-output)
- [Comparing 2 CSV files in C# advice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357195/comparing-2-csv-files-in-c-advice)

Comment: herbalessence- i tried with the linq method that given in the above link. but for a csv having 50000 records it taking 30 seconds to return the result.  So i tried with  hashset that given in the second link and it taking only 2 300 milliseconds to 2second. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

How much information do you need about the differences? If all you need is the fact that they are different and the requirement to have no loops is fixed you could try taking an MD5 hash and comparing the two hashes. If you don't care about memory usage you could just dump the whole stream into a `MemoryStream` call `Getbytes` and then pass the two arrays into `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`

```
private static byte[] GetFileHash(string filename)
{
    using(var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var md5Hasher = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        return md5Hasher.ComputeHash(stream);
    }
}

var file1hash = GetFileHash("file1.ext");
var file2hash = GetFileHash("file2.ext");

var areEqual = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(file1hash, file2hash);
```

Now there are loops being used, just not by you.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way without using loops. How do you expect any compare algorithm to iterate over the characters / words / tokens / lines of the file without using loops?

Anyway, assuming both CSV are sorted by an ID column:

- Try splitting the files into rows
- In a loop

  - Split each row as `List<string>` or as array
  - Compare the lists of both files (ignore trailing empty columns etc.)
  - When differences in data columns were found Save a new row containing the differences into a `List<List<string>>`
  - When different IDs were found, compare both ID: Save the row with the smaller ID (which identifies the additional row) and get the next row of this file

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below to CompareTwoCSVFile and report in another .csv file

```
class CompareTwoCSVFile
{

    public  bool ReportErrorOnCompareCSV(string filePathOne, string filePathTwo)
    {
        var csv = new StringBuilder();
        string[] fileContentsOne = File.ReadAllLines(filePathOne);
        string[] fileContentsTwo = File.ReadAllLines(filePathTwo);

        if (!fileContentsOne.Length.Equals(fileContentsTwo.Length))
            return false;

        string[] columnshead1 = fileContentsOne[0].Split(new char[] { ';' });
        List<string> heading1 = new List<string>();
        Dictionary<string, string>[] dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>[fileContentsOne.Length];
        Dictionary<string, string>[] dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string>[fileContentsTwo.Length];
        string[] headingsplit = columnshead1[0].Split(',');
        for (int i=0;i< headingsplit.Length;i++)
        {
            heading1.Add(headingsplit[i]);
        }

        var newLine = "";
        newLine = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", "File1_ColumnName", "File1_ColumnValue", "File2_ColumnName", "File2_ColumnValue");
        csv.AppendLine(newLine);

        for (int i = 0; i < fileContentsOne.Length-1; ++i)
        {
                string[] columnsOne = fileContentsOne[i+1].Split(new char[] { ';' });
                string[] columnsTwo = fileContentsTwo[i+1].Split(new char[] { ';' });

                string[] cellOne = columnsOne[0].Split(',');
                string[] cellTwo = columnsTwo[0].Split(',');
                dict1[i] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                dict2[i] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                for(int j=0;j< headingsplit.Length;j++)
                {
                    dict1[i].Add(heading1[j],cellOne[j]);
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < headingsplit.Length; j++)
                {
                    dict2[i].Add(heading1[j], cellTwo[j]);
                }
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in dict1[i])
                {
                   if (dict2[i][entry.Key].Equals(entry.Value)!=true)
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine("Mismatch Values on row "+i+":\n File1 "+entry.Key + "-" + entry.Value+"\n File2 "+entry.Key+"-"+ dict2[i][entry.Key]);
                    newLine = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", entry.Key, entry.Value, entry.Key, dict2[i][entry.Key]);
                    csv.AppendLine(newLine);
                   }
               }
            }
            File.WriteAllText("D:\\Errorlist.csv", csv.ToString());
            return true;
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks but what does the code do exactly? Some explanation goes a long way. Do not just post code verbatim